# where can i find source code of abstractuiplugin which is part of eclipse framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, jface

now i am developing kind of eclipse plugin, sometimes i want to debug into eclipse code, i am using eclipse 3.7 and is now trying to find the corresponding code of some eclipse classes, i am seeking these code with this url http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/

lot's of code is included by **Source Build (Source in .zip) (instructions)**
[image]
<sub>(source: [img.itc.cn](http://img.itc.cn/photo/jfRxtXsi4GD))</sub>

but why i cannot find the code of AbstractUIPlugin?
[image]

where i can find the archive which include AbstractUIPlugin? is it part of swing ui framework, or it's part of jface?
any suggestions?

Comment: If you just want to look at the source, you could try this: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin.java.html

Comment: Eclipse does not use Swing

Comment: @jarz i don't want to read it using code search engine, i want to read it in eclipse

Answer (score 3):

This is part of the Eclipse SDK

For Eclipse 3.7 you can install the Eclipse SDK from the `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7` update site (in 'Install New Software').

Once it is installed open the Preferences and go to 'Plug-in Development' and select 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java Search' (since 3.7 is very old I am not sure this actually exists in that release).

Once you have do that you should be able to open any Eclipse source file using the 'Open Type' dialog.